# How can I find a Regex match at a specific location of the string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to find out whether a Regex matches at a specific location of a string.

Example:

```
Regex r = new Regex("d");
string s = "abcdefg";
```

I want the match function to find a match **only** if it is at the exact given location so that using the example above, matching at the locations `1`, `3`, and `5` should give `no match`, `match`, and `no match`, respectively. Unfortunately the C# `Regex.Match` method gives:

```
r.Match(s, 1); // => match ("d")
r.Match(s, 3); // => match ("d")
r.Match(s, 5); // => no match
```

I understand this is because the `Regex.Match` method searches forward for the first match, but how do I prevent this behavior without having to make substrings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\G` to the beginning of your regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\Gd");
string s = "abcdefg";
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(s, 1).Success); // False
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(s, 3).Success); // True
Console.WriteLine(r.Match(s, 5).Success); // False
```

`\G` anchors the match to the position where the previous match ended, or to the beginning of the string if there was no previous match.  With the second argument to `Match`, you're effectively telling it there *was* a previous match, which ended at that location.

Comment: So the second argument overrides the location of any previous match that may have existed?

Comment: `Match()` doesn't normally care about any previous matches.  If you want to find additional matches, you call `NextMatch()` on the Match object it returns.   Maybe I should have said the second argument causes `Match()` to act like `NextMatch()`, pretending there was a previous match that ended at that spot.

Comment: Something to watch out for: `\G` doesn't affect the whole expression, if you have a Regex `\Ga|b` it'll match `a` correctly, but `b` would match everywhere. Use `\G(?:a|b)` for such cases (`(?:)` is a non-capturing group)

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring` and the start-of-string anchor `^`:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^d"); // Use the start of string anchor
string s = "abcdefg";
r.IsMatch(s.Substring(3)); // Match at exactly fourth character (0-based index 3)
```

Alternatively, to avoid copying the string in memory, use quantified `.`:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^.{3}d");
r.IsMatch("abcdefg");
```

The pattern `^.{3}d` says

- Start at the beginning of the string
- Match exactly three characters of anything
- Then match the letter 'd'

Comment: I should have mentioned I want to avoid making substrings unless there is no other way (because it could be inefficient for long strings).

Comment: Problem is, I will be constantly changing the index and switching between a set of multiple regexes.

Comment: You could create the "^.#" part dynamically and concatenate it with the actual regex just before matching it. You can't use "^" in that regex of course, but that should go without saying ;) If you're changing both regex and index very frequently and have performance issues, you could cache the concatenated strings in a lookup-table so that concatenation of each combination happens only once. Trade-in is memory usage of course.

Comment: If I don't know how long my string is, can I use something like `^.{s.Length}d`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're always looking for the same index, you can stuff a little more your regex by adding wildcards at the beginning to "pad" the result, i.e. :

```
Regex r = new Regex("^.{3}d");
r.isMatch("abcdefg"); // true
r.isMatch("adcffed"); // false
r.isMatch("abcddef"); // true
```

On the other hand, if you wanna use the same regex with different indexes, you can just use the `^` character to match the beginning of the string only :

```
Regex r = new Regex("^d");
r.isMatch("abcdefg".substring(3)); // true
r.isMatch("adcffed".substring(3)); // false
r.isMatch("abcddef".substring(1)); // false
```

NB : if you're just looking for a simple string and not a patter, you should simply use [`string.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)

Comment: No, I will be constantly changing indexes and switching between a set of multiple regexes.

Comment: But are these regexes just constant strings? Or do they actually result in variable matches (like `a..b`)? Otherwise tagging `\A` (start of input) in front of the regex and setting the index should work.

Comment: My regexes can be any regex at all so not always constant. `\A` only finds the beginning of the string. So if you start in the middle, it will get nothing.